# Not able to decrease size of legend box R

Tags: r, plot, legend

I'm trying to display 4 plots in the same device window in R. I'm using Linux. However my output is far from pleasant to view.

[image]

As you can see the legend box is quite huge compared the size of the plot. I'm trying to decrease the size of the box; however I'm not able to do it. I've tried positioning the legend, `box.lwd`, `cex`, none of those gave me what I wanted.

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to decrease the size of the box of the legend?

Here is my R code:

```
require survival

survspec <- survfit(Surv(data1$YearEvent, data1$status) ~ data1$Vac, data1)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(survspec,  mark.time=FALSE,  xlab="Time (in years)", ylim=c(0.7, 1), 
     ylab="S(t)", col=c("royalblue", "violetred", "seagreen"))
legend(x="left",legend=c("Yes", "No", "NA"), lty=c(1, 1, 1), 
       col=c("royalblue", "violetred", "seagreen"))
```

The variable YearEvent corresponds to the x axis while the variable status is 0 or 1 and Vac can take three values. It's a Kaplan Meier plot, mainly used in survival analysis

Comment: Can you make your code reproducible?  This will help others troubleshoot the issue.  In this case, `survspec` is not found.

Comment: @Aaron I've added some code. You need the package survival since this is a Kaplan Meier plot. The problem is display 4 plots together, if I display only one plot the legend is perfect. I'm not sure how to tell R to adjust the legend to give space for the remaining plots..

Comment: Thanks, but now `data1` is missing.  I understand that the problem may not depend on these details, but it's very difficult to know exactly what might work to fix it without being able to reproduce what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is use the `cex` set of parameters in your `legend` command.  That will reduce the font size and I believe the symbol size (although you aren't displaying any symbols in this particular case), and thus the entire size of the legend box.

See `?par`  for details.

Comment: Well I've tried that but it decreases also the subtitle in the x axis and y axis.. And it still keep a lot of white space between the categories in the legend.. I would like to decrease only the space in the legend box..

Comment: @pavid I don't see how a `legend(stuff, cex=...)` call can change axis titles.    But if the linespacing is really a headache, you can always manually place three separate (unbordered) legends on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at `y.intersp` parameter in `legends()` function.  Thanks!